# In angular how can we use local variable in ngIf that has been defined in the ngFor loop?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and need the help in implementing the dynamic vertical tabs:

I am using the variable i that I defined in the ngFor loop in the ngIf condition. I don't know how to use the variable i in the ngIf condition. I tried the below code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 <div
          class="pb-5"
          *ngFor="let studentBatch of studentBatchList; let i = index"
        >
          <div
            id="{{ 'tab-content-' + (3 + i) }}"
            *ngIf="currTab == 'tab-content-(3+i)'"
          >
            {{ i + 3 }} <br />
            {{ studentBatch.batchId }}
          </div>
        </div>
```

**TS code:**

```
showtabcontent(id) {
debugger;
id = 'tab-content-' + id;
// this.currTab = 'tab-content-0';
this.currTab = id;
alert(id);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `*ngIf` `i+3` is considered as a string. You must close the single quote before making mathematical operation.

```html
*ngIf="currTab == 'tab-content-' + (3 + i)"
```

Complete example:

```html
<div class="pb-5" *ngFor="let studentBatch of studentBatchList; let i = index">
    <div id="{{ 'tab-content-' + (3 + i) }}" *ngIf="currTab == 'tab-content-' + (3 + i)">
        {{ i + 3 }} <br />
        {{ studentBatch.batchId }}
    </div>
</div>
```